# Deploy Lagom application to Conductr sandbox

Tags: lagom

I would like to deploy a sample app to the Conductr sandbox but i'm confused about the status of some conductr tools for Lagom.
I follow the following tutorial which dates from 25/06/2018: https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-project-using-conductr-sandbox
There also seems to be a good tutorial here: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ConductRSbt.html 
of which I'm not sure if it is outdated (?).

Following projects are marked EOL (End Of Life?) 31/01/2018 which I don't quite understand:

- https://github.com/typesafehub/conductr-cli
- https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-conductr

Effectively I cannot download when adding the following version of the plugin (also tried 2.3.0 without success):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.conductr" % "sbt-conductr" % "2.3.5")
```

It mentions unresolved dependency:

> com.lightbend.conductr#sbt-conductr;2.3.5: not found

Can you shine some light on this?
Are these tutorials still valid, and why doesn't this work for me if they still are?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConductR is no longer being updated. You should investigate other solutions for deploying your services, such as using [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/).

The most current documentation on running Lagom services in production can be found at:

https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/java/ProductionOverview.html (for the Java API)

or

https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/ProductionOverview.html (for the Scala API).

There is also a guide to [Deploying a Lagom application to OpenShift](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/openshift-deployment/lagom/index.html). OpenShift is Red Hat's distribution of Kubernetes, but much of the guide applies equally well to other Kubernetes distributions.